# jquery attr('disabled', 'disabled') isn't fully working in IE (doesn't disable click but looks disabled)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-1.7

I'm having issues with attr('disabled', 'disabled') in internet explorer with jQuery 1.7.1. The buttons appear disabled, however if they're clicked they still execute. In firefox, safari, and chrome, this behaves as expected (does nothing, blocking the click). Any ideas?

```
    disableWizardButtons: function() {
        jQuery(this.wizardButtonSelector).filter(this.enabledSelector).each(function() {
            var button = jQuery(this);
            button.data().originalClass = button.attr('class');
            button.removeClass().addClass('btn-secondary-disabled');
            button.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            button.prop("onclick", null);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Did you know that you only have to write `jQuery` in its long form once? By wrapping your code in `(function($) { .... })(jQuery);`, you can use `$` no matter if `noConflict` has been used or not. And you should use `.prop('disabled', true)` to disable an element. Besides that, on a disabled element usually no events are triggered at all. You also shouldn't try to unbind events by clearing the `onclick` property. If you bound them using jQuery, unbind them using `.unbind('click')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

via ThiefMaster:

> Did you know that you only have to write jQuery in its long form once? By wrapping your
>   code in (function($) { .... })(jQuery);, you can use $ no matter if noConflict has been
>   used or not. And you should use .prop('disabled', true) to disable an element. Besides
>   that, on a disabled element usually no events are triggered at all. You also shouldn't
>   try to unbind events by clearing the onclick property. If you bound them using jQuery,
>   unbind them using .unbind('click').

Answer (score 0):

Normally you could just use

```
button.disabled = true;
```

but since your getting the jQuery obj try

```
this.disabled = true;
```

Comment: The first code won't work on a jQuery object. But `.prop('disabled', true)` will. But his code should work anyway. Or `this.disabled = true;`

Comment: yeah I just added `this` since hes wrapping. I just get frustrated when I see things that are so simple to do in js abstracted by libraries..